# Using a for loop to go through .txt file to calculate a value, but it is only using the final line of data in the .txt file

Tags: python, for-loop

So my input.txt file consists of data like this:

```
Height   Weight
2        70
1.5      60
1.9      80
```

... (with several more lines of numbers following).

I am trying to take that those numbers, put them through an equation to calculate BMI, and output a new txt file with format of height, weight, bmi, and bmi class (e.g. 2, 70, 15, unhealthy).

This is my code I have come up with:

```
infile = open("input.txt", "r")
for line in infile:
    height = float(elements[0])
    weight = float(elements[1])
    bmi = round(weight/(height*height), 1)
    if bmi < 20:
        category = 'unhealthy'
    elif 20 <= bmi <= 24.99:
        category = 'healthy'
    elif 25 <= bmi <= bmi < 29.99:
        category = 'non optimum'
    elif bmi > 30:
        category = 'obese'
    result = height, weight, bmi, category
    print(result)
infile.close()
```

However, when I run it, I only get the same result multiple times in a row:

```
1.66, 53.0, 19.2, 'unhealthy'
1.66, 53.0, 19.2, 'unhealthy'
1.66, 53.0, 19.2, 'unhealthy'
...etc...
```

The first two numbers of that result (1.66, 53.0) are the height and weight of the final line of the input.txt file. The number of outputs I get containing those numbers matches the number of lines of data found in the input.txt file, so it is like the loop is going through each line of the input.txt file but the output is only using the height and weight from the final line of the input.txt file.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: What is `elements`? Did you perhaps mean `line`?

Comment: what is element?

Comment: People have taking time to answer you, please do not deface the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe missing line 4:

```
elements = line.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. You just need to skip the header of the input file 
 if it will always be in the format you provided, by changing the way you are reading the file. I tried this and worked for me:

```
outfile = open("output.txt", "w")
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        elements = line.split()
        height = float(elements[0])
        weight = float(elements[1])
        bmi = round(weight/(height*height), 1)
        if bmi < 20:
            category = 'unhealthy'
        elif 20 <= bmi <= 24.99:
            category = 'healthy'
        elif 25 <= bmi <= bmi < 29.99:
            category = 'non optimum'
        elif bmi > 30:
            category = 'obese'
        result = height, weight, bmi, category
        outfile.write(str(result) + "\n")
        print(result)    
    outfile.close()
```

And got these results for the data you provide in your question:

```
(2.0, 70.0, 17.5, 'unhealthy')
(1.5, 60.0, 26.7, 'non optimum')
(1.9, 80.0, 22.2, 'healthy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this one:

```
result = height + ',' + weight + ',' + bmi + ',' + category
```